# Can I make dplyr's join functions throw an error on unexpected duplicate variables?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

When I do an operation like `inner_join` in dplyr, if both tables have a common column name that is not in `by`, it will use the `suffix` argument to disambiguate the names:

```
> library(dplyr)
> table1 <- tibble(merge_key = letters, unintended_duplicate_col_name = LETTERS)
> table2 <- tibble(merge_key = letters, unintended_duplicate_col_name = seq_along(letters))
> inner_join(table1, table2, by = "merge_key", suffix = c(".1", ".2"))
# A tibble: 26 x 3
   merge_key unintended_duplicate_col_name.1 unintended_duplicate_col_name.2
   <chr>     <chr>                                                     <int>
 1 a         A                                                             1
 2 b         B                                                             2
 3 c         C                                                             3
 4 d         D                                                             4
 5 e         E                                                             5
 6 f         F                                                             6
 7 g         G                                                             7
 8 h         H                                                             8
 9 i         I                                                             9
10 j         J                                                            10
# … with 16 more rows
```

However, in my case, I want the join to abort with an error if the tables have an unexpected common column name. Is there an option I can supply to the join to effectively assert this condition before doing the join? Or do I just have to just check it manually before or after the join?

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach would be to insert a function which checks after joining:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 table1 <- tibble(merge_key = letters, unintended_duplicate_col_name = LETTERS)
 table2 <- tibble(merge_key = letters, unintended_duplicate_col_name = seq_along(letters))

 check_fun <- function(d, su = c(".1", ".2")) {
   if (all(map_lgl(su, ~any(str_detect(names(d), .x))))) stop ("duplicate vars!")
   else d
 }

 inner_join(table1, table2, by = "merge_key", suffix = c(".1", ".2")) %>%
   check_fun()
 # error in check_fun(.) : duplicate vars!
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing now, but it's not entirely satisfactory, because I have to make sure the suffixes I use won't accidentally appear as suffixes of the original column names. Also, there's a minor mistake in your code: `str_detect` treats the suffixes are regular expressions, not fixed patterns to match, and it also doesn't enforce that they occur at the end of the column name. So for example, if the merged table had columns named was "This1IsNotADuplicate" and "This2ShallPass", it would throw an error.

Comment: Maybe creating a not-convertible value is a way out.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that `suffix` is not lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes the most sense to check for unused duplicate columns before the join:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(5)
table1 <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(3, sample(letters))), c("a", "b", "c"))
table2 <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(3, sample(letters))), c("a", "b", "d"))
 
check_join <- function(x, y, by, ...) {
  stopifnot("Unexpected common column" = length(setdiff(intersect(names(x), names(y)), by)) == 0)
  inner_join(x, y, by, ...)
}


check_join(table1, table2, by = "a")

Error in check_join(table1, table2, by = "a") : Unexpected common column 

check_join(table1, table2, by = c("a", "b"))

  a b c d
1 f j i p
2 w i y s
```